# mongoid association reference to an embedded model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mongoid

I have following setup

```
Class Country
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name
  field :code

  has_many :locations
end

Class Location
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :country
  field :region
  field :city

  has_many :locations
  embedded_in :company
end

Class Company
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name

  embeds_one :location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :location
end
```

Countries model is seeded with all the countries.

Countries get stored with their 2-letter shortcode in Location model through a nested form. For example "US".
Now I want to call @company.location.country.name in the the View to get "United States", however I'm getting an error

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
```

How do I go about doing this?
What's the best way? 
I'm new to MongoDB so I apologize if this is a stupid question

Comment: why don't you have a `has_and_bleongs_to_many` relation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is related to the reverse relation you are defining on Country. Yes, a Location can have a Country but the Country can't link to the Location as it's an embedded document.

Try removing the `has_many :locations` in the Country class. This should solve it. Don't define a reverse relation if you don't need it.

If you need the reverse relation you probably don't want it as an embedded document.

Answer (score 1):

This won't work for the given reasons (embedded & relations).

On an other side, for your issue, you shouldn't store the full name of countries in your db.

Indeed this is a "fixed" list, and to be precise, it is ISO-3166-1. Embrace the standards when there is one (rare!). A good way is to use locales (and you spare the seeding, syncing, updating parts).

Considering the file `config/locales/iso-3166-1/en.yml` :

```
en:
  countries:
    AD: "Andorra"
    AE: "United Arab Emirates"
    AF: "Afghanistan"
    AG: "Antigua and Barbuda"
    ...
```

Now, you can use `I18n.t(@mylocation.country, :scope => :countries)`.

Bonus, it is i18n / l10n ready: `config/locales/iso-3166-1/fr.yml` :

```
fr:
  countries:
    AD: "Andorre"
    AE: "Émirats arabes unis"
    AF: "Afghanistan"
    AG: "Antigua-et-Barbuda"
    ...
```